# Guild Wars 2 Chests content dependent on killing its boss?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In noticed that in the later maps in Guild Wars 2, there are some bosses with chests. Some of those chests can be opened by distracting the boss or sneaking to the chest. However, my attempts (with sample size N=very small), those chests didn't contain anything nice.

So my question is:

Is the content of chests in Guild Wars 2 dependent on the boss it belongs to being killed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no evidence that the drops from an existing chest improve after killing the mini-boss guarding it. They generally just don't contain very exciting loot.

More powerful "bosses" (such as the priests of each god in Orr) actually spawn a giant, glowing chest after they are defeated. Those bosses *must* be killed to access the chest - and they have a better chance of good loot, but it's still not great.